# C# - AddStore not working properly in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook-2007, outlook-2007-addin

I have been attempting this all morning (VS2K10, OL2K7, .NET 3.5) and my PSTs never attach.  I've modified the path to include escaped slashes, no dice.  I occasionally see the PST get added then disappear when I hit the command bar button for which I am trying to program.

Here is a snip of my code:

```
void b_removedPSTs_Click(Office.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
{
  string PSTToAdd = dd_removed_PSTs.Text;

  foreach (PSTWithPath p in removedPSTs)
  {
    if (PSTToAdd == p.name)
    {
      olApp.Session.AddStore(@p.path);
    }
  }

  UpdateRemovedList();

}
```

PSTWithPath is a custom class I've created as follows:

public class PSTWithPath
  {
    public string name;
    public string path;
    public Outlook.MAPIFolder mapifolder;

```
public PSTWithPath(string PSTName, string PSTPath, Outlook.MAPIFolder PSTMAPIFolder)
{
  name = PSTName;
  path = PSTPath;
  mapifolder = PSTMAPIFolder;
}
```

Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: Updated info:  I can successfully add a PST from a local drive, but the network drives are where I'm having an issue.  (and, yes, I know that PSTs on a network are hazardous...that's part of why I'm writing this add-in for my users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.  It seems that the function was being case sensitive.  Not sure if this was a MS or Novell thing, but it's working now.